# Service Fabric Configuration Array

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

In ASP.NET Core I can use configuration arrays like this in appsettings.json:

```
{
  "MySettings"
      "MyArray": [
          "str1",
          "str2",
          "str3"
      ]
   }
}
```

Can I have configuration arrays in Azure Service Fabric? If yes - how?

Comment: You could comma separate the values in a single string and split it

Comment: @MartinBrandl thanks Martin, this is my second option, but I'd prefer an array if it's possible. The setting value will be pretty long. I need to put 20-50 connection strings in it.

Comment: Yeah, got you. That was the solution I was end up with but didn't invest much time so looking forward for a better solution.